# Отправка красивого письма в форму по ajax

Tags: php, email

Есть у меня форма на сайте, все работает.
скидываю образец файла email.php который отвечает за высылку письма

```html
<?php

$recepient = "мойимейл@gmail.com";
$sitename = "имясайта";

$name = trim($_POST["name"]);
$phone = trim($_POST["phone"]);
$text = trim($_POST["text"]);
ну и дальше много всяких переменных

$message = "
тут собственно сообщение которое будет приходить на почту



";

$pagetitle = "Новая заявка с сайта \"$sitename\"";
mail($recepient, $pagetitle, $message, "Content-type: text/plain; charset=\"utf-8\"\n From: $recepient");
```

Проблемма в том что я хочу чтобы разметка была красивая. 
Чтобы работали теги h1 h2 h3. Цвета. Отступы. Может есть готовое решение на Bootstrap? Если да то как это подключить? 
А то я ставлю наиример тег

```
<h1>Заголовок</h1>
```

Мне так и приходит. h1. А я хочу чтобы были большие буквы.
Подскажите кто знает как внедрить?

Answer (score 2):

Нужно указать Content-type: text/html

```
<?php

$recepient = "мойимейл@gmail.com";
$sitename = "имясайта";

$name = trim($_POST["name"]);
$phone = trim($_POST["phone"]);
$text = trim($_POST["text"]);
ну и дальше много всяких переменных

$message = "
тут собственно сообщение которое будет приходить на почту



";

$pagetitle = "Новая заявка с сайта \"$sitename\"";
mail($recepient, $pagetitle, $message, "Content-type: text/html; charset=\"utf-8\"\n From: $recepient");
```

Comment: Большое спасибо. Сделал. Все получилось.
Может знаете как присвоить перевод некоторым словам. Например приходит value austria, а я хочу чтобы писало Австрия..  phpMailer не подключал.